# how can i stop function loop in discord.py (

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm doing a bot discord and I want to engage a function who check all the "x" seconds the time who functions but I tried 7000 things to stop it (when I put `!stop`) but nothing function..
I saw on other stack overflow, `my_task.cancel` but that doesn't work, can someone help me and explain me where is my problem please.

```py
go = True

async def my_task(ctx, username):
    while go == True:
        # await ctx.send("tic tac boum")

        now = datetime.now().time() # time object

        print("now =", now)
        print("type(now) =", type(now)) 
        await asyncio.sleep(3)


@bot.command()
async def infoo(ctx, username):
    bot.loop.create_task(my_task(ctx, username))

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    #ici
    #want to stop this fcking function
    print("alaid")
```

and my task gives: (if I just do `bot.loop.create` that s function)

```
my_task = bot.loop.create_task(my_task(ctx, username))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_task' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: are you forgetting `go = False` ? to stop while loop.

Comment: i did but that doesn't function :s

Comment: in, my function stop

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to come off as rude, but don't copy code blindly without understanding what it does. `my_task.cancel` will only work for a task.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=3)
async def my_task(ctx, username):
    # do stuff here
    # you don't need to sleep, the task handles that

@commands.command()
async def start(ctx, username):
    my_task.start(ctx, username)

@commands.command()
async def stop(ctx)
    my_task.stop() # or my_task.cancel()
```

You could also do this with an [Asyncio Event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), but it would vary a little.

### References:

- [tasks-api](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#api-reference)
- [tasks-examples](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#recipes)

### Note:

If you don't understand what `@tasks.loop(seconds=3)` does, I suggest you read more about [OOP](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/object-oriented-programming) and [decorators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator).